# Process.Start returns false even though the process is started

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

we have in our application following function:

```
public static Process StartApp(string fileName, bool waitForProcessExit)
{
    Process proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            ErrorDialog = false
        }
    };

    bool processStarted = proc.Start();

    if (!processStarted)
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (errorCode == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unknown Error!");
        }

        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
    }

    if (waitForProcessExit)
    {
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }

    return proc;
}
```

When this function is executed, the variable `processStarted` contains `false` under some circumstances. That happens when e.g. a Microsoft Word file is opened and Word is already running (same happens to Excel). When using a .jpg file as parameter the result is the same: `Process.Start` returns false.

Our applications needs to be blocking when parameter `waitForProcessExit` is true.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) that appears to be the behavior by design. **Return Value: true if a process resource is started; false if no new process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused).**